# Passing action and controller values from view to another partialview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple index views with a different grid in each of these views, but all of them uses the same popup control. I dont want to make a partial view foreach index view that i have. So i put the popup partial view in the Shared folder.

But i have a **Html.BeginForm('Action','Controller')** in the popup partialview, and these values are different in each grid. How can i pass these from the view of the grid to the partial view of the popup?

The Grid View:

```
  //Code Resumed
  @Html.DevExpress().GridView(
  settings =>
  {
    settings.Name = "TestMasterGrid";
    settings.Column.Add("Id");
    settings.Column.Add("Name");
    settings.Column.Add("Email");

    //Command Column Wich calls the popup control
  }
```

The PopUp PartialView:

```
//Code resumed
using (Html.BeginForm("ActionINeedToGetFromTheGridView", "ControllerINeedToGetFromTheGridView", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
                textBoxSettings =>
                {
                    textBoxSettings.Name = "reason";
                    textBoxSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "editor";
                })
            .Render();

            Html.DevExpress().Label(
                labelSettings =>
                {
                    labelSettings.Name = "sh";
                    labelSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
                }).Render();
            Html.DevExpress().Button(
                buttonSettings =>
                {
                    buttonSettings.Name = "btnUpdate";
                    buttonSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
                    buttonSettings.Width = 80;
                    buttonSettings.Text = "OK";
                    buttonSettings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                }
            )
            .Render();
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'Action' and 'Controller' are strings right? Why do you add those to your model?

Comment: @mart Yes! Both are just simple strings.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the action and controller names to the action that returns the PartialViewResult. Then, pass the names to the partial's model and use them in the BeginForm statement:

```
Html.BeginForm(Model.Action, Model.Controller, FormMethod.Post)
```

Edit:

I'm not very familiar with DevExpress, but I found the `CallbackRouteValues` member in settings. I'll use that for my example:

```
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "ControllerName", Action = "GetPartialView", desiredAction = "DesiredAction", desiredController = "DesiredController" }
```

In your controller, you'd have the `action` and `controller` parameters:

```
public PartialViewResult GetParialView(string desiredAction, string desiredController) {
    var viewModel = new PartialViewModel { Action = desiredAction, Controller = desiredController);
    Return PartialView("Name", viewModel);
}
```

I typed out this code by hand, so it's probably full of errors. Hopefully it gets the idea across, though.

Quick edit: changed some parameter names to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Sorry i dont get it. You mean, put the string values into my model?

Comment: In your command to populate the partial view, pass the desired action and controller values to the action you call. I'll edit with an example real quick.